# Text not in line Word Mac

Tags: macos, microsoft-word

I'm trying to make the text in Word Mac OS inline with the other text I have. How do I fix this?

See example here. (Text not inline with the red line)

[image: See example here. (Text not inline with the red line)]

Comment: Do you have different page margins on the two pages?

Comment: Do you have 'mirrored margins' set up? For example, on the Layout tab, if you open the Page Setup dialog box, is Mirror margins selected in the Multiple pages field on the Margins tab? (That's where the setting is in Word for Windows, at least; I assume it must be similar in Word for Mac.) If so, just select another option for margins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the image you shared, I would say the alignment differences are do to the document's margin settings. On Word for the Mac the quick way to open the **Document Layout/Margin** dialog is from the **Menu Bar** at the top of the window and select **Format > Document ...**

[image]

The first thing to check is if there is a setting on **Gutter**. Gutter is a term from old Typesetting days and it provides a little extra room for the binding of the printed pages into a book. So, if both the left and right margin settings are identical, the inclusion of a Gutter setting could cause the alignment difference you are seeing.

If the Gutter setting is zero, and the left and right margin settings are not the same, the other setting to double check is under the **Multiple Pages** menu that I've captured in the screenshot above. If the option to **Mirror Margins** is set that will swap the left and right margin settings on odd and even pages in the document. The reason for this is for printing on front and back of pages ... and again think about the binding of pages. Even if you don't use the Gutter setting you can still get the same effect by having a little extra room on the "inside" margin where the document will be bound.

Finally, you tagged your post with macros. If you are trying to control the page layout of your document with macros, the VBA commands to look into:

```
With ActiveDocument.PageSetup
    .LeftMargin = Word.InchesToPoints(0.5) ' or word.CentimetersToPoints
    .RightMargin = Word.InchesToPoints(0.5)
    .MirrorMargins = True
    .Gutter = Word.InchesToPoints(0.3)
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

You could right-click the two differently-styled paragraphs, choose "Paragraph..."
and compare their attributes.

It would be much simpler to click on a good paragraph and type
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>,
then select all the bad paragraphs and type
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.

The first copies the paragraph's style, while the second applies/pastes it to the
target paragraphs.